# EF CodeFirst-Migration on copied database want to run initial migration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I copied a database from production. The difference with my Dev-DB in terms of tables / fields is just one field. That field gets added by the last code-first migration. The only migration that was not applied in production.

Now I copied an Azure DB to a local SQLExpress on my dev machine through an export import of the DB in a SQL-script (schema + data). The application runs fine as long a I do not need that one field of course. I wanted to add that field by running 'Update-Database' and apparantly VS wants to apply to first 'initial' migration. Why ? I checked the db for the __MigrationHistory table, it has it and the only record that is missing is the one than has the migrationid from that very last migration.

Any help to understand what is going on and to solve it is appreciated. How is VS update-database determining which migration it should apply ?

UPDATE:

EF6

Output of update-database -verbose

```
    PM> update-database -verbose
    Using StartUp project 'Mapato'.
    Using NuGet project 'Mapato'.
    Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
    Target database is: 'MapatoCopyProductie' (DataSource: localhost\SQLEXPRESS_JSL, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
    Applying explicit migrations: [201505170635248_Init, 201505191015284_[ActivityMaster] Added Duration, ...........

<continued list of all migrations>

Applying explicit migration: 201505170635248_Init.
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Activities] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [TenantId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [WorkYearId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EnrollMentFee] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Currency] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RequiredAgreementId] [int],
    [ActivityMasterId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Info] [nvarchar](max),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Activities] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'Activities' in the database.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
ClientConnectionId:913026de-19a7-4ba5-83ea-dc5403995540
Error Number:2714,State:6,Class:16
There is already an object named 'Activities' in the database.
PM>
```

Comment: EF version? Which is the output of the update-databse if you run it with the `-verbose` parameter?

Comment: Try generating an idempotent script (update-database -script –SourceMigration $InitialDatabase) then you can walk through it and compare it to what is in your __MigrationHistory table. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#idempotent  If you just want to get it working you can comment out the existing stuff in the Up() method and apply it so you are up to date again. You could also re-establish your baseline (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx#option1).

Comment: How is EF actually deciding which migration to apply or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work again. I do not understand why it works now, but that's what I did :

from another post I learned that it was worthwhile checking the origin in :

Target database is: 'MapatoCopyProductie' (DataSource: localhost\SQLEXPRESS_JSL, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration)

I noticed that the name was configuration. I re-factored the configuration class to a more meaningfullname, so I would have expected that name there. Changed it back to configuration and I works again. Guess it has to do with 'convention over configuration' and if nof 'configuration class' is found it chooses some default that did collide with what needed to be done.